# Mobile pagination

Tags: mobile, e-commerce, pagination

I was working on pagination for mobile (e-commerce) where this option is offered at the bottom of the page. We didn´t place it on the top due to space limitation and also filter. However I was wondering whether there are some ideas UX friendly that there would be an option to make the pagination somehow always visible to the user on mobile.Is there a way to showcase him this page selector in between his scrolling behavior?

Comment: do you have a mock of this, or how are you envisioning it?

Comment: Hi @Devin, imagine, you are a user and you go to POV (product overview) page of any eshop. On the top you have filters, sub-categories and similar. On the very bottom of the POV you would have pagination option. My question is: Is there a way how to indicate/navigate/inform user while scrolling content on the POV, that he/she has a possibility to "go to pages" that is being placed on the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use pagination. I've seen several SEO issues in the past (might have been solved, not big on SEO). But mostly, pagination puts unnecessary constraints on the product view.

I'd use a "Show more" or "Load more" button to extend the list. Christian Holst has an article on this on [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/pagination-infinite-scrolling-load-more-buttons/).

That being said, having pagination at the bottom (where it usually is) is not a bad thing, so long it's clear, easily accessible with a large enough click/tap area and it gains enough attention so it's not overlooked. Users would scan the page they see most likely and see if the products listed are what they want. If not, they'll filter it. If it is, they will scroll to the bottom anyway, or stop to look at a product.

Answer (score 1):

Sticky pagination isn't exactly common behaviour in an e-commerce setting. It also doesn't really make much sense in my opinion to have it be sticky at the top. The point of pagination is that you chunk results and offer more once the user has run out of content to browse. So having this be at the bottom makes the most sense. Why would someone want to skip to the next/different page if they don't know yet what's on it?

If you want to give people a rough estimate how much they can (still) expect on the page no matter where they're at, you can make the result amount sticky next to the filtering. I personally don't think having a sticky pagination solves any usability issues. Pagination is a common element on the web. Your users will know that if they scroll, they will either reach the end or are given more pages/load more buttons to continue browsing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.upon download and first launch you can have a short tutorial that shows navigation between pages can be achieved with right to left swipes...
2. have low opacity of left and right arrows in the middle of screen on each side respectively that shows that you can go to next or prev page by clicking the arrows
3. have break points between content while scrolling that has numbers pagination 
....just to name a few quick solutions

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, could you please clarify the 3rd point? I am not sure I understood well.